# how to logout completely from instagram account from my website

Tags: instagram

On my website i fetched data using instagram api. Whoever user loggedin his uploaded photos will display on the page. When i click on logout i expire all session like session_destroy(); and session_unset(); and it expires all sessions and redirect to index.php. But when i click on login, it automatically logged in without asking userid and password.
I want when i expire session the accounts also logout from instagram. How to do that?
here is site link [sachanrealityhomes.com/technovidemo/instagram/](http://sachanrealityhomes.com/technovidemo/instagram/) (click on Create)

Answer (score 6):

Thats cause you have just destroyed your website session, Instagram is still logged in, you have to logout of Instagram. You can logout of Instagram by opening URL: https://instagram.com/accounts/logout

You can do something like this in JS:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "https://instagram.com/accounts/logout";
$("head").append(s);
```