# Instagram OAuth not asking which account I want to give access to

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

When my application hits the authorization URL it skips the entire screen. It automatically grabs my corporate Instagram account, and I don't want it grabbing the wrong accounts for my users too.

> Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL
>
> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
>
> At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a
> confirmation screen where to grant your app access to her Instagram
> data.

Are there any options/ arguments that I can pass with `.authorize_url` it to prevent the skipping of the auth page?

```
  def authenticate
    redirect_to (Instagram.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri))
  end

  def callback
    if params[:code]
      response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to logout of instagram before doing oauth login using APIs.

Here is answer to logout of instgram: [how to logout completely from instagram account from my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646380/how-to-logout-completely-from-instagram-account-from-my-website)

Comment: Hmm. Thinking about how I could run `https://instagram.com/accounts/logout` before my auth route.

Comment: when you show your page that has "connect to instagram" button, do the logout in the script for that page onready.